# SQL xml export help - Exporting fields based on values of other fields

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a SQL xml export which provides me with the value of 3 fields and exports without issue. The 3 fields in question are called Day, Night and Weekend - What i'm trying to achieve is if there is only a value in the day field and nothing in the other two then I want to export just the day field alone, completely omitting the Night & Weekend fields. If there is a Night rate entered then I want to export the day and night field and if there is a weekend field entered then I want to export all 3 fields.

Is it possible to achieve this within a single select statement? as i'm not too sure how I would do with within the xml containers.

This is what I have currently which exports okay with all the fields in:

```
(SELECT --Product Item--    
'ENERGY' ProductItemReference,
    (SELECT --Rates--
        (SELECT --Rate--
            DAY AS Rate, --Mandatory
        'Unrestricted' RateName
            FOR XML PATH('Rate'), TYPE),
        (SELECT
            NIGHT AS Rate,
        'Night' RateName
            FOR XML PATH('Rate'), TYPE),
        (SELECT
            WEEKEND AS Rate,
        'Evening and Weekend' RateName
            FOR XML PATH('Rate'), TYPE)
    FOR XML PATH('Rates'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('ProductItem'), TYPE)
```

The data within the select statement could contain multiple accounts some with only day rates and others with night and weekend. Can I export each account out in the correct format mentioned above within the one select statement?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

DC

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's makes it easier to for us to help you if you include sample data and expected output.  Take a peek [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Both pages contain some great tips.  If you follow those I'm sure the answers will come.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `case when ... then ... end` to choose what rates you want to export?

Without knowing what you data is like (I've used a table variable) or how you want the output to look could would something like this work?

```
declare @srcTable table(dayRate int, nightRate int, weekendRate int);

insert into @srcTable(dayRate, nightRate, weekendRate)
select 451 dayRate, null nightRate, null weekendRate union
select 452 dayRate, 453 nightRate, null weekendRate union
select 454 dayRate, 456 nightRate, 457 weekendRate;

select 'Energy' ProductItemReference,
    (
        select
            (select 'Unrestricted' [@name], dayRate[*] for xml path('Rate'), type),
            case when nightRate is not null then (select 'Night' [@name], nightRate [*] for xml path('Rate'), type) end,
            case when weekendRate is not null then (select 'Evening and Weekend' [@name], weekendRate [*] for xml path('Rate'), type) end
        from @srcTable
        for xml path('rates'), type
    ) 
for xml path('ProductItem'), type
```